# Why is my 7-column tabular(x) wider than specified?

Tags: tables, tabularx

I want a very simple table (`tabular/x/*`, whatever) with 7 columns, each 14% percent of the `\linewidth`, 98% total.

But for some reason the rightmost column is a) on the margin, b) outside the table rules.
[image]

How do I fix it?

```
\documentclass[version=last,12pt]{scrreport}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
\tiny
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}
p{0.14\linewidth}
p{0.14\linewidth}
p{0.14\linewidth}
p{0.14\linewidth}
p{0.14\linewidth}
p{0.14\linewidth}
p{0.14\linewidth}
@{}
}
\toprule
Excavator
& Alphanumeric data 
& Location 
& Warranty details 
& Expiry date of the support period 
& Required business properties
& Maximum needed diesel
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but what's the point of using `tabularx` if you employ only `p` columns?

Comment: In your calculations, you did not take into account the value of tabcolsep that is added to the left and right of each column. Thus your table is as wide as 7*0.14\textwidth+12*\tabcolsep.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to simply use \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}*{7}{X}@{}}?

Comment: @leandriis It is, I didn't know the trick. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to remove all intercolumn space you can also use `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}*{7}{p{0.14\linewidth}@{}}}` (repeating the `@{}` after each `p` column), but the output is really ugly, better use @leandriis' solution

Comment: @ It's all `p` because I wanted to use left-justified `p` columns. Probably, I need to make a customized `X` too.

Comment: @homocomputeris: Contents of `p` type columns are justified by default, not left aligned and so are `X` type columns. If you want left aligned rather than justified contents, you can either use ` \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}*{7}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}@{}}` or define your own column type as follows `\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}` and use it with `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}*{7}{L}@{}}`.

Comment: Add a `@{0}` after all but the last `p` specifier. You need to remove the extra space between columns.

Comment: @HerbSchulz: `@{0}` should probably be`@{}`as the former will just add a `0` in front of the text in the following column's cells. However, please be aware that this approach will result in a rather unpleasant output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJdr9.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First version: Using `tabularx`'s `X` type columns results in a table that is exactly as wide as the textwidth and consists of 7 equally wide columns. In order to left-align the columns, I used `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}` and defined a new custom column type `L`.

Second version: Here, I manually caclulated the column widths taking into account the value of `\tabcolsep` which is added to the left and right of each column's contents. As you can see, the resulting table is, as expected, slightly narrower than the textwidth.

Third version: In this version, I used `tabular*` in combination with `\extracolsep{\fill}}` to make sure the table is as wide as the textwidth.

The vertical lines in the following screenshot are cause by the `showframe` package and show the textwidth/beginning of the margins.

[image]

Side note: I hope, the `\tiny` font size was just used in this example. As this font size is quite hard to read as it is that tiny, I recommend not using it. You could easily fit the table into the textwidth, even with a regular font size, resulting in an output similar to

[image]

Depending on the table's contents, it might also be beneficial to allow different column widths.

```
\documentclass[version=last,12pt]{scrreport}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\newcolumntype{Z}[2]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr #1\textwidth- #2\tabcolsep} }

\newcolumntype{Y}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr #1\textwidth} }

\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
\tiny
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}*{7}{L}@{}}
\toprule
Excavator
& Alphanumeric data 
& Location 
& Warranty details 
& Expiry date of the support period 
& Required business properties
& Maximum needed diesel
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[t]
\tiny
\begin{tabular}{@{}Z{0.14}{1} 
                   *{5}{Z{0.14}{2}}
                   Z{0.14}{1} @{}}
\toprule
Excavator
& Alphanumeric data 
& Location 
& Warranty details 
& Expiry date of the support period 
& Required business properties
& Maximum needed diesel
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[t]
\tiny \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{7}{Y{0.14}}}
\toprule
Excavator
& Alphanumeric data 
& Location 
& Warranty details 
& Expiry date of the support period 
& Required business properties
& Maximum needed diesel
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```